# Delete Azure storage blob given a URI

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cli

I am working on a cleanup script that deletes an Azure image and its underlying storage blob. I can find the storage blob for my image with this command:

```
az image list --query "[?name=='$IMAGE_NAME'] | [].storageProfile.osDisk.blobUri"
```

(This is bash, so `$IMAGE_NAME` gets replaced with the actual image name). The output of the above command is a JSON list of URIs, each looking something like this:

```
https://storage_account.blob.core.windows.net/container_name/blob_name.vhd
```

Looking at the documentation for [az storage blob delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_blob_delete), I can tell that this blob can be deleted with a command like this:

```
az storage blob delete --account-name storage_account --container container_name --name blob_name.vhd
```

So, obviously I can parse the URI and then generate this command. However, this seems odd: what's the point of giving blobs a URI if you can't use them?

So my question is:

1. Is there a direct az cli command to delete a blob by using its URI?
2. Better yet, is there a way to delete the blob associated with a given Azure image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in CLI command to delete with blob url directly. There is a workaround to use [`az rest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az_rest) to call the [Delete Blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delete-blob) REST API.

```
access_token = $(az account get-access-token --resource https://storage.azure.com/ --query accessToken -o tsv)
now = $(env LANG=en_US TZ=GMT date '+%a, %d %b %Y %T %Z')
headers = "Authorization=Bearer "+$access_token+" x-ms-date="+$now+" x-ms-version=2020-08-04"
az rest --method delete --uri $blob_url --headers $headers
```